# How do I implement a 2-3-4 tree?

Tags: java, b-tree

Deleted old question and wrote a better one. So I had no idea of how am I supposed to do this, so I thought I was supposed to use a linked list, but it seemed like there would be limitations. I noticed a few packages related to trees, such as [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/package-summary.html).

That also didn't seem to fit what I wanted to do, then I started thinking of creating a class for nodes with methods such as `IsThere2Nodes` or like `IsParentOf(x)`, etc. I'm being a little vague, but I just want to know if I am I approaching this in the right direction.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree

Comment: Ignore anything in the javax namespace. It is not want you want for a data-structure -- it is for Swing/UI. Since you are implementing your own tree, it is likely you will have your own Tree and Node classes. It is *highly suspect* of being incorrect if a LinkedList or Array (or any other "standard" data-structure) is used at the top-level.

Comment: I think you want a Node interface and three implementation Node2, Node3, and Node4.

Comment: @Thilo YES! I think that's it!

Comment: @Thilo - I don't think an interface and three implementations is the way to go. That would make rebalancing the tree more difficult because nodes would have to become different objects when the tree was rebalanced after an insert or delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely should be creating a class to represent a node of the tree.

To get going, consider the definition of a 2-3-4 tree. A node needs three slots for data and four slots for child pointers. It also needs some sort of indication of how many of these are in use at any particular time. That's the data. Then you need operations on nodes to support the operations on the tree. Analyze how to do each tree operation in terms of what you would do to the nodes and you should be able to figure it all out.

Comment: Upvoted! Could you guide me a little more? So I'm thinking, I would have to create a lot of objects for the vast amount of nodes? Am I supposed to have them point at each other or something to know who the parent is? I think I am thinking about this wrong. What if I want to search the whole tree? Then this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @Doug - Start simple, with a class that seems to do what you need for a node. Then represent your tree as simply a reference to the root node. Then start implementing each tree operation you want. If you find that you need more functionality at each node (such as `getParent()`), just add it in. Don't add functions to the node class until you discover that you actually need them. (I don't know that you need a separate tree class; think of a node as synonymous with "the (sub)tree rooted at this node". If you decide you need a tree class, it can contain the reference to the root node.)